# The measure of set

Tags: measure-theory

Is it exist a closed set $E$ that is subset of $[a,b]$, $E \neq [a,b]$, which measure is $b-a$? I think, it exists, but can't find an example.

Comment: What do you mean by $<>$? Do you mean $\neq$? If so, use `\neq` to render it.

Comment: If $x\notin E$ and $E$ has full measure, then every open interval in $[a,b]$ containing $x$ must contain an element of $E$.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if so, what kind of set is $(a,b)\setminus E$? What is the measure of it? Is this possible? Why or why not?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen It does provide a very strong hint what the answer is.

Comment: Yes, but hints should usually go as comments!

Comment: @kjetil: This not *remotely* a critique or a request for clarification. And it is *extremely* common practice to answer with hints that lead to the desired conclusion. Still, your opinion is noted, even if I disagree with it, and your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Set $(a,b)\setminus E$ is open. The measure of it is $b-a-(b-a)=0$. It is not possible. Thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome. Do you see why it isn't possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. If $ E $ is a closed subset of $ [a,b] $ and $ E \subsetneq [a,b] $, then $ [a,b] \setminus E $ contains an open interval and so must have measure $ > 0 $. This implies that $ \mu(E) < \mu([a,b]) = b - a $.